# Rails: Connecting one model to another through forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, settings, form-for

I am currently running into a problem of connecting one model to another. Basically I want a user (user model) to be able to select a specific school (school model) through a form and the user will be under that specific school until they change it. I can't figure out how to exactly go about doing this, any help will be much appreciated! Thank you!

**user model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :biography, :avatar
  has_secure_password
  belongs_to :school, foreign_key: "school_id"
end
```

I have nothing defined for anything of school in the user model cause I am not sure what to put.

**school model**

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :school_id

  has_many :users

  validates :school_id, presence: true

end
```

**user controller**

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    redirect_to @user
  else
    redirect_to current_school
  end
end

def update
 @user = current_user
 if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated profile."
  redirect_to home_path
 else
  redirect_to current_school
 end
end
```

**school controller**

```
def create
  school = School.find(params[:name])
   if school
   session[:school_id] = school.id
   redirect_to school_path(school)
  end
end

def show
  @school = School.find(params[:id])
  @user = User.new
end
```

**Form for User with school inside**

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
<%= f.label :Name %></br>
<%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'modal_settingfield' %>
</br></br>
<%= f.label :Email %></br>
<%= f.text_field :email, :class => 'modal_settingfield' %>
</br></br>
<%= f.label :Password %> <span class='faded'>(Leave blank to not change)</span>
<%= f.password_field :password, :class => 'modal_settingfield'%>
</br></br>
<%= f.label :Password_Confirmation %> <span class='faded'>(Leave blank to not change)</span>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class => 'modal_settingfield'%>
</br></br>
<%= f.label :School_id %> <span class='faded'>(Leave blank to not change)</span>
<%= f.association :school, collection: @schools, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, prompt: "Select a school", :label => false, :required => false %>
<%= f.label :Biography %> <span class='faded'>(Please limit Biography to <span class='TextCounter'></span>letters)</span></br>
<%= f.text_area :biography, :class => 'modal_settingfield'%>
</br></br>
<%= f.label :Photo %> <span class='faded'>(Add a Profile Picture)</span></br>
<%= f.file_field :avatar %>
<%= f.submit 'Update', :class => 'update_button' %>
<% end %>
```

**Current School**

```
def current_school
  @current_school ||= School.find(session[:school_id]) if session[:school_id]
end
helper_method :current_school
```

**Sessions Controller(This is login code)**

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
    if params[:remember_me]
      cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
    else
      cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
    end
    redirect_to home_path
  else
    flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
    redirect_to current_school
  end
end

def destroy
  cookies.delete(:auth_token)
  redirect_to current_school
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the [simple_form gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) for this type of thing, and in general for easier, cleaner and less verbose forms. See the section on Collections.

You'd have code like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :school_id, collection: @schools, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, prompt: "Select a school" %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

This assumes that the `@schools` variable is set by the controller action that renders this form. I'm assuming that these would be `School` objects, having `:name` and `:id` methods.

Also, your `School` model should probably not have `school_id` as `attr_accessible`, I think you want this on the `User` model, along with the validation rule. You also don't need to set the foreign key explicitly if you're following the conventional naming, i.e.:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :school_id, :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :biography, :avatar
  has_secure_password
  belongs_to :school

  validates :school, presence: true
end
```

Comment: I implemented the simple_form_for and one I am getting an undefined method for f.input :user and two if I remove that, the values and label are not on the f.input :school_id, it is just a text area, I am very confused. Sorry for the inconvenience I am new to rails and learning.

EDIT

I actually used f.association rather than f.input and it is showing now, only issue is when I update, it doesn't update

Comment: @BrianKim Sorry my bad. A copy & paste error of mine; this example is taken straight from the simple_form_for readme. The arguments to `input` are the attributes, e.g. :name.  I've edited the answer to correct this. Sorry.

Comment: @BrianKim Regarding the second half of your comment: f.association is probably the better choice, but it just calls f.select underneath. Can you post your full form again now and the UsersController actions for update and create, to help troubleshoot?

Comment: I just edited everything you asked for, everything works great but one problem I continuously run into now is when I sign up, the id of the school clashes with the user id and when I sign up the form picks up on the user id number and uses it as the school id number, how can I fix this?

Comment: @BrianKim I can't diagnose this without seeing your login code. Are you using Devise? Is this somehow related to your `current_school` method? How is this method implemented?

Comment: @BrianKim I think you've mis-interpreted your problem. When the `UserController#create` action runs, the form operates on a new `User` object which doesn't have an ID yet.

Comment: What would be a solution that may work, because when signing up, I need the user to pick a pre-exisiting school that already has a id

Comment: @BrianKim the form you have should do the trick, although I'd suggest you use simple_form's `input`. Then make sure you have a validation rule on the user model to require the presence of `school_id`.